# One of telemetry initializers failed, telemetry item will not be sent

Tags: javascript, angular, azure, azure-application-insights

I have tried all 3 implementations: including the [JS snippet](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS#use-js-snippet-and-initialize-dynamically-download-full-application-insights-script-from-cdn), importing the [module](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS#import-as-a-module-and-initialize-dynamically-download-full-application-insights-script-from-cdn) and simply calling `downloadAndSetup()`, and the 3rd party [ApplicationInsightsModule](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/angular-application-insights). With all 3 on the first 404 error the client code causes by passing `undefined` url to native `XMLHttpRequest` is followed by the warning:

> AI: TelemetryInitializerFailed message:"One of telemetry initializers failed, telemetry item will not be sent: TypeError" props:"{exception:[object Error]{ stack: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null\n    at c (https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js:3:1690)

Looking at the global appInsights object I see the only TelemetryInitializer is at [TelemetryContext.ts:141](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/JavaScript/JavaScriptSDK/TelemetryContext.ts#L141)
[image]

How do I debug the fact the `remoteData.baseData.name` is `null` and shouldn't the `dropBrowserLinkRequests` TelemetryInitializer defined in ApplicationInsights own `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryContext._addDefaultTelemetryInitializers()` work out of the box?

I have no special configuration other then the instrumentationKey. I'm simply including the snippet or calling `downloadAndSetup()`.

Edit Update:
[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/HUXeEVozVIRc2aVfHvZE?p=preview) is a plunker to demonstrate. Replace instrumentationKey in index.html. It happens specifically with `XMLHttpRequest` and not `fetch` and specifically when `undefined` url is passed to `XMLHttpRequest.open()`.

Comment: It is a bug ([#534](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/issues/534)) and maybe will be corrected in the [1.1.0 milestone](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/milestone/22).

Comment: Cool I made that github issue when I didn't get a response on here. Now I see it has the "Bug " label.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the error with App Insights version 2.0.  I've updated to 2.7 and the error is no longer there.